# How do I add a rich text box to a Custom Post Type in Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to add a custom post type for 'surgeons' unfortunately theres like 6 sections i need to add which need to be rich text and not plain text for images, etc. this is what i currently have.

I have all the plain text fields working fine but now i need to add all rich text ones.

Set up various structures on backend

```
function personal_meta() {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);

  $email =   $custom["email"][0];
  $phone =   $custom["phone"][0];
  $address = $custom["address"][0];
  $website = $custom["website"][0];
  ?>

  <p><label>Email:</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></p>

  <p><label>Phone - with extension. i.e. (805) 555-2323 Ext 234</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" /></p>

  <p><label>Address:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="address"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea></p>

    <p><label>Website - BEGINNING WITH http://</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website; ?>" /></p>

  <?php
}
```

heres the code to save it

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

```
function save_details(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "email", $_POST["email"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "phone", $_POST["phone"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "address", $_POST["address"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "website", $_POST["website"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class "theEditor" which will then add the tinyMCE editor to the `textarea`:

```
<textarea class="theEditor" cols="50" rows="4" name="address">
    <?php echo $address; ?>
</textarea>
```

However, that will strip out `<p>` and `<br>` tags (not any others) when saved.

To prevent stripping those tags, you will need to try something like this:

```
<textarea class="theEditor" cols="50" rows="4" name="address">
    <?php echo wpautop(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your text area', true)); ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to do deep works, as on update_metadata , wordpress uses sanitize_meta function, which sanitizes the meta value, and thus, you may get plain value.